# showing four random images

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am using this code to generate random image to UIImageView. When I click the button, it apears another image. I would like to ask you how to create four imageviews - click button -> apears four different random images.

ViewController.h

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController {
   IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView;
   // IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView2;
}
-(IBAction) randomImage;
```

ViewController.m

```
- (IBAction) randomImage {
NSArray *images = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"image1.jpg", @"image2.jpg", @"image3.jpg", @"image4.jpg", nil];
int count = [images count]
int index = arc4random() % count; 

 imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[images objectAtIndex:index]];
// imageView2.image = ....
}
```

I created four imageViews in storyboard and I was trying something like above // imageView2.image...  but it it not the right solution :-)
Thank you for your help

Answer (score 3):

Code to list 4 random image:

```
NSMutableArray *images = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray: @[@"image1.jpg", @"image2.jpg", @"image3.jpg", @"image4.jpg"]];
int countImg = images.count;

for (int i = 0; i < countImg; i++) {
    NSInteger index = arc4random() % images.count;
    NSLog(@"Image%d name = %@",i , [images objectAtIndex:index]);
    [images removeObjectAtIndex:index];
}
```

Comment: Instead of arc4random() % count use arc4random_uniform(count) to eliminate bias.

Comment: I did count number of image before do loop

Comment: @jbouaziz There is no real memory inefficiency compared to creating and displaying the image. In any event the key is against pre-mature optimization, instead write for clarity. Later if there are performance issues profile and address the real issues.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using `IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView;`, use `IBOutletCollection(UIImageView) NSArray *imageViews;` and connect all of your image views to this.

Then, in your code:

```
- (IBAction) randomImage {
    NSArray *images = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"image1.jpg", @"image2.jpg", @"image3.jpg", @"image4.jpg", nil];
    NSInteger count = [images count];

    for (UIImageView *imageView in self.imageViews) {
        NSInteger index = arc4random() % count; 

        imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[images objectAtIndex:index]];
    }
}
```

Comment: It displays a random one, but one can be displayed more than once.

Comment: +1 for `IBOutletCollection`, -1 for repeated images.